# C# StringBuilder to String to use in an XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, stringbuilder

I have to run through a ton of really messy and inconsistent xml documents, some of which have multiple root nodes. I want to use XmlDocument. What I have done is using XmlReader with ConformanceLevel.Fragment, I append each line using ReadOuterXml() to a StringBuilder string. When looking at the StringBuilder string it looks fine, but when I go to add it to the XmlDocument with LoadXml, I have to converto it to .ToString(), which then messes it up.

It make this

```
<info version="1.3.1.3-en" />
```

look like this

```
<info version="\&quot;1.3.1.3-en\&quot;" />
```

Here is the code I use to create the XmlDocument

```
    public XmlDocument createXDocFromReader(string fi, string parentNode)
    {
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlReaderSettings readerSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        readerSettings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
        StringBuilder xmlString = new StringBuilder();

        xmlString.Append("<" + parentNode + ">");


        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(fi, readerSettings))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                xmlString.Append(reader.ReadOuterXml());
            }
        }

        xmlString.Append("</" + parentNode + ">");

        xDoc.LoadXml(xmlString.ToString());

        return xDoc;
    }
```

Comment: where/how are you looking at the stringbuilder?

Comment: At the end of the building it up inside the XmlReader .Read() loop. So before the loop, I add my own parent node, then loop, then close the parent node. Then its xDoc.LoadXml(xmlString.ToString()); , xDoc being the XmlDocument and xmlString being the StringBuilder string.

Comment: I have found that if the xml to be loaded isn't properly formed (there could be a missing closing node or a missing closing quote or something like that) it will do stuff like that.

Comment: I have grabbed the string while it is in the StringBruilder string and it looks just fine. It is only once I convert the StringBuilder to String does it add all that other stuff.

Comment: You need to show the code where you convert the StringBuilder to String.  And the load where you load the XML data.

Comment: Added the function I use to create the XmlDocument.

Comment: Don't use StringBuilder for that, go for XmlWriter or anything that understand xml structure.